# porque me sale este error?

Tags: sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al momento de querer ejecutar el select, me indica que debo declarar lo q pide, pero eso no esta ya declarado?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Si estás ejecutando solo esa línea puntual claramente `@alumno` no esta declarado, sino es el caso, agrega a tu pregunta, la sentencia completa de lo que estás ejecutan y que te da error, y por favor en forma de texto y no de imagen. Saludos